# Filtering dropdown selectable values depending on the selected value on another dropdown - in a content creation page

Tags: forms

I have 3 content types: "Floors", "Spaces" and "Resources".
One floor can have multiple spaces, and one space can have multiple resources.

"Floor" has only a title field;
"Space" has a title field + a reference to the "Floor" entity;
"Resource" has a title field + a reference to the "Floor" entity + a reference to the "Space" entity.

Is it possible to have a "Resource" creation page with 2 dropdowns, where the user first picks the "Floor", and then picks the "Space" on a second dropdown that shows only spaces in that previously selected floor? I suspect this may have to do with filters but I had no luck so far.

Thank you.

Comment: Nodes are not hierarchical by default, so this is not possible out of the box. But there are modules for hierarchical selection of taxonomy terms like [Client-side Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/cshs).

Comment: This can be done with Drupal’s AJAX API.

Comment: Thanks Hudri, will check the module. cilefen mind to give me some light on your suggestion? Is that functionality in Drupal? (Im using version 10)

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/drupal-apis/ajax-api

Comment: thanks will check it